# how to instal steam in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: command-line, games

You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6

please help me

Comment: To be honest - I'd start with installing latest version of Ubuntu first. Then - if Steam is 32bit application you'll need to install 32bit versions of some libraries - including libc.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 is no longer supported and therefore, this question is off-topic here. Please upgrade to a currently supported version of Ubuntu (12.04, 14.04, 15.10 and 16.04 in a few weeks)

Comment: my pc is 64 bit